# Stop a regex matching *everything* after what I want to actually match!

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am quite new to the whole Regex thing and tried to do a `preg_match_all` in PHP which, kind of the results I wanted but the problem is it matches everything **after** what I actually wanted... like so:

String: `This is something <code>Some code here</code> and more`
Match from Regex: `<code>Some code here</code> and more`
Wanted match from Regex: `<code>Some code here</code>`

Here is my regular expression that I'm using:
`/<code>(.*)<\/code>/`

I think its something to do with the beginning and ending `/` delimiters but I'm not entirely sure.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The star is *greedy*, meaning it will match as much as it can. Use

```
(.*?)
```

instead, making it *lazy*. You can also use negated character classes:

```
!<code>([^<]*)</code>!
```

*EDIT*: Since mvds deleted his/her answer, here's a tip: You can avoid having to escape the slash (`/`) if you don't use it as a delimiter, like I did above ^ (used `!` )

Here's a good resource on regex:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: This is the only one that seemed to work out of all the answers! Thanks!

Comment: regex.info also has some examples dealing with HTML tags (the 1st one): http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Answer (score 2):

you want to make the `.*` be non greedy. If you put a `?` after that part of the pattern it will match everything up to the next part of the regex that matches. So make the regex `/<code>(.*?)<\/code>/`

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable greediness.  Use `.*?` instead, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how this is even compiling - you need to escape the second `/` as so:

```
/<code>(.*)<\/code>/
```

So that PHP recognises it as a character to match rather than the end of the regular expression (I think it may be compiling as a substitute regex).

Comment: Turns out I was escaping it anyway, forgot to put in my code on here...